# IBM i series data queue sending and receiving speed is slow on i7

Tags: db2, queue, ibm-midrange

I am working with an `IBM i-series` machine. The problem is that since we have migrated from `i5` OS to `i7` our data queue sending and receiving speed has been degraded extremely and it's going to be bothersome. All database files and data queue parameters are the same and we have expected to have a better performance but I cannot find the problem. Is there anybody who can tell what can be the problem? Am I missing something to check??

Comment: How full is your data queue? If it contains more records than the initial increment can hold, that can be the cause of slowness.

Comment: Do you mean you upgraded i/OS from Version 5.something to version 7.something?  I don't know what might be going on, but having exact from/to information may be helpful for someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy yes. it contains more records than the initial increment but the situation was the same on OS i5 too and we had not the problem. it's happening on i7.